# Consider app.config remapping of assembly "log4net" from Version "1.2.13.0" to Version "2.0.8.0"

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

After updating Nuget version and updating various package versions in our build, I'm getting a compiler warning on one specific project.

> C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5):
>   warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects"
>   property to true in the project file. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.

And also the warning in the question title.

When running the application I get a crash relating in assembly version mismatch, which ties in with this. And the warnings make sense, BUT what I can't figure out is why it thinks 1.2.13.0 is in use. I cannot find a reference anywhere. And more crucially, another similar project doesn't get any of these warnings and works fine; neither project file has any reference to AutoGenerateBindingRedirects. It must be coming from somewhere and I don't really want to start hacking project files without knowing why.

Comment: So you are completely sure that this project or any other project it references (or any third party library it references) do not use log4net 1.2.13?

Comment: How would i determine that for sure?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45454885/42809